# How to run linux (ubuntu) commands in python script?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have a program folder for which paths are required:

```
export RBT_ROOT=/path/to/installation/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$RBT_ROOT/lib
export PATH=$PATH:$RBT_ROOT/bin
```

Then the command is run:

```
rbcavity -was -d -r <PRMFILE>
```

rbcavity - is an exe program contained in the program's bin folder

PRMFILE - is the program contained in the current path (working folder not included in the program folder)

This works from the command line, but not from python. How can I run this from a python script (3.5)? I tried subprocess.run but it doesn't find the command rbcavity... I'm new to linux and don't quite know how it works.

Comment: Where are those `export` statements being executed?

Comment: subprocess.run(["export", "PATH=$PATH:$RBT_ROOT/bin"], shell=True)

Comment: Could you add that to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
subprocess.run(["export", "PATH=$PATH:$RBT_ROOT/bin"], shell=True)
```

only sets the `PATH` environment variable in the subprocess (and any of its child processes, if it had any).  Therefore, it's unchanged in your Python program which is why your executable couldn't be found.

To set an environment variable in Python, use `os.setenv`.  I.e.,

```
rbt_root='/path/to/installation/'
path = os.getenv('PATH')
path += ':'+rbt_root+'bin'
os.setenv('PATH',path)
```

EDIT:

So, it turns out that `os.setenv` isn't very portable.  Instead, use `os.environ`, which is dictionary-like.  E.g.,

```
os.environ['PATH'] = path
```

Comment: It gives me an error:  module os has no attribute setenv

Comment: Which version of Python is this?

Comment: 3.5 and in the meantime I read that it is impossible to change the shell environment from python script...

Comment: It’s impossible to change the shell’s environment from Python.  However, Python change the environment of itself and all of its descendant processes.

Comment: It turns out that `os.setenv` isn't portable.  I've updated my answer to include a better solution.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I think the problem is running rbcavity - python doesn't seem to see it even after inserting the full path.

Comment: As a sanity check, are you sure you have execute permission for that file?

Comment: Yes, I have. I also try to run this as a bash file but it won't work.

Comment: OMG I made a mistake in the name of one environment variable. Now it is working. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use OS library. I am using the following commands to run and start the Cassandra server. In the end to run this, I do python filename.py

```
import os
os.chdir('./dsc-cassandra-3.0.9/bin')
os.system('./cassandra start')
```